# This is a tough one!

Tags: cipher

Can you crack this code?

Hint : It decrypts to an English plain text word(s) and no one-way hashes have been used!

**Code**

> 31 30 35 20 31 32 31 20 31 30 31 20 36 38
>
> 20 37 30 20 37 31 20 35 34 20 31 31 39 20
>
> 31 31 34 20 37 34 20 37 35 20 36 35 20 31
>
> 32 32 20 31 30 36 20 35 33 20 31 30 38 20
>
> 31 30 31 20 37 33 20 31 31 36 20 31 31 32
>
> 20 39 30 20 31 31 34 20 31 31 31 20 38 32
>
> 20 38 34 20 31 31 31 20 31 31 30 20 38 39
>
> 20 31 31 35 20 35 37 20 31 30 39 20 36 36
>
> 20 35 38 20 35 38 20 34 39 20 35 30 20 35
>
> 31 20 35 32 20 35 33 20 35 34 20 00 00 00

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer(?):

> It's interesting that with the exception of the three `00`s at the end, all of the numbers are either `20` or `30` through `39`. Those happen to be the hex for the ASCII codes for space and the numerals `0` through `9`. Taking that as a "first level" encypher, I get **105 121 101 68 70 71 51 119 114 74 75 65 122 106 53 108 101 73 116 112 90 114 111 82 84 111 110 89 115 57 109 66 58 58 49 50 51 52 53 54** and three terminating NULs.  The next logical step is to assume that these are again ASCII codes - in Decimal this time - and take their printed representations: `iyeDFG6wrJKAzj5leitpZroRYonYs7mB::123456`. Unfortunately, this is as far as I've been able to go; it's not a base-64-decodeable string.

Comment: What interests me is the ending `::123456` in the printed representations of the decimal ASCII codes. I wonder if that could be a clue?